# Python problemas para crear y rellenar un array bidimensional

Tags: python-3.x, lista, array-bidimensional

Quiero crear un array bidimensional digamos de 4x4 lleno con ceros y después llenar la fila 0 y fila 3 con unos y la columna 0 y 3 con unos. El código sería:

```
arr = [[0] * 4] * 4
for i in range(4):
   for j in range(4):
      if i == 0 or i == 3 or j == 0 or j == 3:
         arr[i][j] = 1
```

cuando compruebo el resultado veo que es:
[[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
es más si hago:

```
arr[3][2] = 5
```

me rellena toda la columna 2 con el valor 5, no sólo la posición [3][2]

En cambio si hago lo siguiente:

```
arr2 = []
for i in range(4):
   if i == 0 or i == 8:
      arr2.append([1]*4)
   else:
      arr2.append([0]*4)

for j in range(4):
      arr2[j][0] = 1
      arr2[j][3] = 1
arr2[3][2] = 5
```

funciona todo correctamente.
[[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 5, 1]]

Sin embargo ambas listas tienen la misma estructura una lista que con tiene 4 listas de 4 elementos. En C++ una estructura idéntica a la primera funciona correctamente creando un array [4][4] y recorriéndolo para rellenarlo con 1 en las condiciones i == 0 or i == 3 or j == 0 or j == 3 y con 0 en caso contrario.

Esto lo añado posteriormente:
Parece que si hago un apend y luego cambio los valores sí que funciona:

```
arr2 = []
for i in range(4):
   arr2.append([0]*4)

print(arr2)
for i in range(4):
   for j in range(4):
      if i == 0 or i == 3 or j == 0 or j == 3:
         arr2[i][j] = 1
```

[[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]

Es en el caso 1 cuando creo la estructura llena de ceros que no funciona como debería. ¿Alguien sabe porqué tiene este comportamiento tan extraño cuando las estructuras de los tres ejemplos son idénticas?
arr = [[0] * 4] *4

Comment: Prueba con esto `a=[[0] * 4 for _ in range(4)]` y agregalo a tus meditaciones.

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly

Answer (score 1):

Traducido de: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly

Cuando escribes `[x]*3` lo que obtienes esencialmente es la lista `[x, x, x]`. Es decir, una lista con tres referencias al mismo `x`. Cuando modificas este único `x`, la modificación es visible a través de sus tres referencias:

```
x = [1] * 4
l = [x] * 3
print(f"id(x): {id(x)}")
# id(x): 140560897920048
print(
    f"id(l[0]): {id(l[0])}\n"
    f"id(l[1]): {id(l[1])}\n"
    f"id(l[2]): {id(l[2])}"
)
# id(l[0]): 140560897920048
# id(l[1]): 140560897920048
# id(l[2]): 140560897920048

x[0] = 42
print(f"x: {x}")
# x: [42, 1, 1, 1]
print(f"l: {l}")
# l: [[42, 1, 1, 1], [42, 1, 1, 1], [42, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Para evitar esto, necesitas asegurarte de crear una nueva lista en cada posición. Una manera de hacerlo es:

```
[[1]*4 for _ in range(3)]
```

que reevalua `[1]*4` en cada pasada, en lugar de evaluarlo una sola vez y luego hacer tres referencias a una lista.

Podrias preguntarte por qué * no puede crear objetos independientes tal como lo hace la comprensión de listas. La razón es que el operador multiplicativo * opera con objetos, sin ver expresiones. Cuando usas * para multiplicar `[[1] * 4]` por 3, * solo ve la lista de un elemento que resulta de evaluar `[[1] * 4]`, no el texto en la expresión `[[1] * 4]`. * no tiene idea de como hacer copias de ese elemento, ni idea de como reevaluar `[[1] * 4]`. Ni siquiera sabe si quieres copias y, en general, puede que no haya forma de copiar el elemento.

La única opción disponible para * es crear nuevas referencias a la sublista existente en lugar de intentar crear nuevas sublistas. Cualquier otra cosa sería inconsistente o requeriría un rediseño mayor del lenguaje.

Al contrario, una comprensión de listas reevalua la expresión del elemento en cada iteración. `[[1] * 4 for n in range(3)]` reevalua `[1] * 4` cada vez por la misma razón que `[x**2 for x in range(3)]` reevalua `x**2` cada vez. Cada evaluación de `[1] * 4` genera una nueva lista; la comprensión de listas hace lo que necesitas.

Incidentalmente, `[1] * 4` tampoco copia los elementos de `[1]`, pero no importa, ya que los enteros son inmutables. No puedes hacer algo como 1`.value = 2` y convertir el 1 en 2.

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado la respuesta a porque la estructura [ [0] * n] * m no funciona como esperaba.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly